# How To Add Double Quotes To Every Number In The Same Column In Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have a data like the below in one of the columns in the table and I need to add double quotes to every string. Could anyone advise how to do this in Postgres?

Actual Data:

```
["607"]
["586,603"]
["586,603","900"]
```

Expected Output:

```
["607"]
["586","603"]
["586","603","900"]
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Is the column an array of string ?

Comment: It is just a column of text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use function `REPLACE`:

Step 1: Replace all `","` to `,`

Step 2: Replace all `,` to `","`

EX:

```
UPDATE TABLENAME SET COLUM_NAME=REPLACE(REPLACE(COLUM_NAME,'","',','),',','","')
```